# logic for checking what is the input data

Tags: c

can any one help me in this logic, when i enter a source ip is should call a particular function XXX()if i enter destination ip or destination port or source port it should call a different function say YYY(), my doubt is how can i recognise whether the input address is source ip address or destination address

Comment: What? Please give us an example of what you're doing? Are you reading input from `stdin`? UI? Command line arguments?

Comment: How do you recognize whether it is source or destination? IP is IP and they do not have a different format if they are source or destination

Comment: is `1.2.3.4` a source or destination address?

Answer (score 0):

With assumption that you are referring to Command Line Arguments.
You should have options to your program.
For example :

```
program_name --source-ip <source ip> --source-port <source-port> --destination-ip <destination-ip> --destination-port <destination-port>
```

You should then parse those and call the functions accordingly.